# Ionic MySQL notification

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ionic-framework, notifications

I’m still learning about ionic and I’d like to know if my ionic application has any way of knowing when a new row is inserted into a table in mySQL.

The context of this is because I have a program that detects falls of older adults, doing so inserts the date of the fall into a table, so I am interested in receiving notification to the application when a new row is inserted in my table.

Is it possible to achieve that ?, Since I do not know how to make my application constantly listen to a URL.

Comment: You can achieve this by using observables or promises, take a look at https://www.joshmorony.com/an-introduction-to-observables-for-ionic-2/

Comment: @RicardoVallejo The problem is that the code that inserts the date of the fall is in python, so I do not know how to do so that my observable listens to that external event.